# Xpath and namespace, select node iterator

Tags: java, xpath, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I have this kind of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<documentAnswer xmlns="http://schemas.pkh.hr/doc/2013/documents/rda_30" domainName="rda" domainVersion="3.0">
<answerTimestamp>2013-08-21T13:35:25.894</answerTimestamp>
<correct>
    <docId>RDA2_29F81D27-1409BE49E2E-7FF8</docId>
    <attachments>
        <attachment>
            <format>application/pdf</foraat>
            <generatedType>StampanNaBlanko</generatedType>
            <encodedPdf>JVBERiYKJSVFT0YK</encodedPdf>
        </attachment>
    </attachments>
</correct>
```

Those *attachment* tags can be one or more. I am trying to get NodeIterator of *attachment* tags in java using

> XPathAPI.selectNodeIterator(node,
>   "/documentAnswer/correct/attachments/attachment")

and then iterate, but I am not succeeding. I am guessing that problem is in xpath and that it is related to namespace, but don't know how to solve it. I tried with this kind of xpath but no success:

> XPathAPI.selectNodeIterator(node,
>   "/rda:documentAnswer/correct/attachments/attachment", "rda",
>   "http://schemas.pkh.hr/doc/2013/documents/rda_30")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/rda:documentAnswer/correct/attachments/attachment
```

Here you are assigning the `rda` namespace only to the root element, but it is declared in the XML as the *default* namespace. Therefore, *all* your elements are in that namespace. You must use

```
/rda:documentAnswer/rda:correct/rda:attachments/rda:attachment
```

Unfortunately, the XPath standard does not support the declaration of a default namespace.

Answer (score 0):

3 kind of approach :

**A-Embed namespace for query QNames and not only local-names()**

with corrected header :

```
<ns0:documentAnswer xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.pkh.hr/doc/2013/documents/rda_30" domainName="rda" domainVersion="3.0">
```

xpath

```
    /ns0:documentAnswer
```

**B-Query only local-names with local-name() function**

```
    /*[local-name()="documentAnswer"]
```

**C-Query local-names and namespaces (querying QNames)**

```
    /*[local-name()="documentAnswer" and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.pkh.hr/doc/2013/documents/rda_30']
```

see http://nealwalters.blogspot.fr/2005/01/common-xpath-examples-questions-issues.html

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer you can get it ignoring the namespaces this way:

```
/*:documentAnswer/*:correct/*:attachments/*:attachment
```

Comment: Only in XPath 2.0.  If this is Xalan's XPathAPI we're talking about then it only supports XPath 1.0, which allows `prefix:*` but not `*:localname`.

Comment: @Ian Roberts, Yes you are right. My mistake to ignore it, sorry that!